Bounded operators on the span of a set of vectors
Let $E$ be a Banach space and $S$ a subset of vectors in $E$. Suppose that a linear operator $T$ satisfies the property
$$\|Tx\| \leq C \|x\| \text{ for all }x \in S.$$
Does this imply that $T$ is bounded on $\text{span}(S)$? I found a similar question here which asks about boundedness of $T$ on $\overline{\text{span}(S)}$, where the answer was "no," but I am unsure if that is still the case when one does not take the closure.

If a linear operator is unbounded on the closure of a subspace it is unbounded on this subspace.

@RyszardSzwarc That’s simply not true. You can take a dense subspace $V$ and take a bounded linear functional on it. Then extend to an unbounded linear functional on the entire space by extending a Hamel basis of $V$ to a Hamel basis of the entire space and extend the linear functional in an unbounded manner on the remaining basis vectors (which is what the answer in the question OP linked to did).

@DavidGao  You are are right, the extension can be made in a sort of artificial way.  The natural bounded extension is unique.

@RyszardSzwarc Yeah. You would certainly be right if the operator in question is a densely defined closed operator. But based on the question the OP linked to, the question seems to be about everywhere defined unbounded (so necessarily not closed) operators.

No. Let $T: l^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a linear map s.t. $Te_n = n$. Then let $S = \{e_1\} \cup \{e_n - e_{n-1}: n \geq 2\}$. Note that any for any $x \in S$, we have $T(x) = 1$ and $\|x\| \geq 1$, so $\|Tx\| = 1 \leq \|x\|$ for all $x \in S$. But $e_n \in \text{span}(S)$ for all $n$ and $Te_n = n$, so $T$ is unbounded on $\text{span}(S)$.

I prefer the following straightforward example. For an infinite orthonormal system $S=\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in a Hilbert space let $Te_n=e_1.$ Then $\|Te_n\|=1$ and
$$\|e_1+e_2+\ldots + e_n\|=\sqrt{n},\ \|T(e_1+e_+\ldots +e_n)\|=n$$ Hence $T$ is unbounded on the linear span of $S.$
